# move QlineF inside QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I try to understand, how to move/transform graphic items inside a QGraphicsScene.

In my code i define a QGraphicView with a scene as QGraphicsScene. Then I create a line "l2" with QLineF. Then I define "l2" as a QGraphicsItem "lnk" and define pen, isSelectable and isMovable.
I add it to the scene with "addItem"

Afterwords I read the start and endpoint, manipulate the endpoint and want the line be updated in the scene.  Here I fail.

My Code is

```
self.gvCanvas.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 501, 501))
self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()


l2 = QtCore.QLineF(100,100,300,70)
penlnk = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black,3,QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
lnk = QGraphicsLineItem(l2)
lnk.setPen(penlnk)
lnk.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
lnk.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
self.scene.addItem(lnk)

pt1 = l2.p1()
pt2 = l2.p2()
xpos = pt2.x()+1500
ypos = pt2.y()
ypos = ypos+500
ptnew=QtCore.QPoint(xpos,ypos)
l2 = QtCore.QLineF(pt1,ptnew)
```

I tried "setLine(l2)", "scene.update()" and others. Nothing works.

I could delete the line "l2" first and then create it new. But this is for sure not the right way !?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QGraphicsLineItem copies the value of l2, so the modification of l2 will not modify QGraphicsLineItem, what you must do is set the new line to the item using [setLine()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicslineitem.html#setLine), this method will internally call the `update()` method:

```
# ...
ptnew=QtCore.QPoint(xpos,ypos)
l2 = QtCore.QLineF(pt1,ptnew) 
lnk.setLine(l2)
```

---

Your previous code can be reduced to the following:

```
self.gvCanvas.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 501, 501))
self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()

l2 = QtCore.QLineF(100,100,300,70)
penlnk = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 3, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
lnk = QGraphicsLineItem(l2)
lnk.setPen(penlnk)
lnk.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
lnk.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
self.scene.addItem(lnk)
l2.setP2(l2.p2() + QtCore.QPointF(1500, 500))
lnk.setLine(l2)
```

Comment: thank you, it works ! (and thanks for the "oneline"-statement with the points